# jest input on change not triggered/simulated

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a `React` component that looks like this. It's a simple form with an `input` element of type `email`. As usual, when the user types some text, I fire a callback for the `onChange` event. This is what the code looks like.

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from "react";
import CheckCircleOutline from "mdi-react/CheckCircleOutlineIcon";
import AccountOutlineIcon from "mdi-react/AccountOutlineIcon";
import styles from "./ForgotPassword.module.scss";

class ForgotPasswordFrom extends PureComponent {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      email: ""
    };
  }

  updateEmailField = e => {
    this.setState({ email: e.target.value });
  };

  resetPassword = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email } = this.state;
    this.props.onSubmit(email);
  };

  render() {
    const { showResetMessage, email } = this.props;
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <form className="form aim-form">
          {!showResetMessage ? (
            <Fragment>
              <div className="form__form-group">
                <div className="form__form-group-field">
                  <div className="form__form-group-icon">
                    <AccountOutlineIcon />
                  </div>
                  <input
                    name="email"
                    type="email"
                    onChange={this.updateEmailField}
                    placeholder="Enter Registered Email Address"
                    className="email-input"
                    data-testid="forgot_password_input"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary account__btn account__btn--small login-btn"
                onClick={this.resetPassword}
                data-testid="forgot_password"
              >
                Submit
              </button>
            </Fragment>
          ) : (
              <div className={styles.messageContainer}>
                <CheckCircleOutline size={50} />
                <div className={styles.emailMessage}>
                  <div>We have sent an email to {email}.</div>
                  <div>Click the link in the email to reset your password</div>
                </div>
              </div>
            )}
        </form>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default ForgotPasswordFrom;
```

I am trying to write a test for when the input field's change event is simulated. This test should basically ensure that the `updateEmailField` function is triggered. However, no matter what I try, I cannot get the test to pass. The error I get is that the mock function is not called.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
  it("should have called the function", () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<ForgotPasswordForm />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    instance.updateEmailField = jest.fn()

    const input = wrapper.find(`[data-testid='forgot_password_input']`);
    input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test ' } });
    expect(instance.updateEmailField).toHaveBeenCalled();

  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
it("should have called the function", () => {
  jest.spyOn(ForgotPasswordForm.prototype, 'updateEmailField');
  const wrapper = mount(<ForgotPasswordForm />);
  afterAll(() => {
    ForgotPasswordForm.prototype.updateEmailField.mockRestore();
  });
  const input = wrapper.find(`[data-testid='forgot_password_input']`);
  input.simulate('change', { target: { value: 'test ' } });
  expect(wrapper.instance().updateEmailField).toHaveBeenCalled();
})
```

Comment: Nope I tried this, but it didn't work. It says expected a function, but got undefined.